# Exercise 3.5.17 Jech-Hrbacek ordered $n$-tuples in $\mathsf{ZF}$

Tags: set-theory

I am working on the exercises in chapter 3, section 5, of "Introduction to Set Theory" by Hrbacek and Jech. In exercise 5.17 the authors make a definition for ordered $n$-tuples and suggest an hint to solve it, but I don't understand how solve it. Can you help me?

The exercise is the following:

> Define $n$-tuples so that
>
> $ \ $ (a) $(a_{0})= a_{0}$
> $ \ $ (b) $(a_{0}, a_{1},\dots, a_{n}) = ((a_{0},\ldots,a_{n-1}), a_{n})$, for all $n \ge 1$
>
> [*Hint*: Say that $a$ *is an $n$-tuple* if there exist finite sequences $f$ and $ \langle a_{0},\dots,a_{n-1}\rangle$ of length $n$ such that
>
> $ \ $ (i) $f_{0} = a_{0}$
> $ \ $ (ii) $f_{i+1} = (f_{i}, a_{i+1})$, for $0 \leq i < n-1$,
> $ \ $ (iii) $a = f_{n-1}$
>
> Show that for each $n$-tuple $a$ there is a unique pair of finite sequences $f$, $\langle a_{0},\dots, a_{n-1}\rangle$ of length $n$ such that (i), (ii) and (iii) hold; we then write $a = (a_{0},\dots, a_{n-1})$. Show that for every finite sequences $\langle a_{0},\dots,a_{n-1}\rangle$ of length $n$ there is a unique $n$-tuple $a = (a_{0},\dots, a_{n-1})$. Then prove (a) and (b).]

Comment: The authors provide you with the definition, you just need to verify it satisfies the property of $n$-tuples.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how the definition of the predicate "be an $n$-tuple" works for the case $n=0$ and I don't know why I have to show that for every finite sequences $<a_{0}, \dots, a_{n-1}>$ of length $n$ there is a unique $n$-tuple $a=(a_{0}, \dots, a_{n-1})$.